Verifying constructor calling another constructor
I want to verify Foo() calls Bar() without actually calling Bar(). And then I want to verify that obj is assigned with whatever Bar() returns.
I tried the following:
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, a):
        print(a)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = Bar(1)

###

import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from mod import Foo, Bar

@pytest.fixture # With stdlib
def mock_bar():
    with patch('mod.Bar') as mock:
        yield mock

def test_foo(mock_bar):
    result = Foo()
    mock_bar.assert_called_once_with(1)
    assert result.obj == mock_bar

But it would fail and say that:
E       AssertionError: assert <MagicMock na...='5265642864'> == <MagicMock na...='5265421696'>
E         Full diff:
E         - <MagicMock name='Bar' id='5265421696'>
E         ?                                 ^ ^^
E         + <MagicMock name='Bar()' id='5265642864'>
E         ?                     ++          +  ^ ^


Why exactly do you want to write a test like that? Why can't you just instantiate Bar? Why do you want to mock it?

@ndc85430 Bar is a third-party thing which involves some network requests.

You are patching the object Bar, but you don't consider the default value a=1.Could you retry your test with  self.obj = Bar() in your Foo-class only. Just in case I would also check that mock_bar.assert_called_once_with() is used with the same / correct variable.

@baskettaz Sure. I updated my code, and it asserts the call is indeed made, and is still failing at the comparison line.

This line:
assert result.obj == mock_bar

Should be:
assert result.obj == mock_bar.return_value

It is the result of calling Bar which gets assigned in self.obj = Bar(1), not Bar itself.

Thank you, I'm still too noob to make the distinction between the mock and its result.

You could do it also directly in your mock_bar as yield mock.return_value but it depends of your context and your preference. I think that the above solution serves you best.
